# Redimensioning a picture in an outlook message

Tags: excel, object, outlook, range, shapes

I am trying to change the size of a range of cells I am copying from Excel into an Outlook message.

The range of cells is pasted as a picture. Now how can I resize the picture?
I thought I need to create an object / a shape and set the object to be the range of cells. How could I do that?

This is what I have:

```
Dim wEditor As Variant
Dim rng As Range

    Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With objMail
        .Display
    End With

    Set wEditor = objOutlook.ActiveInspector.WordEditor

    Set rng = Worksheets("Interface").Range("B38:O117")

    rng.Select
    Selection.CopyPicture

    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

Word provides the Macro Recorder which allows to record the steps made manually and generate the required code for you automatically. See [Record or run a macro](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Record-or-run-a-macro-cd56fb86-d8b2-475c-ba39-9728389feeeb) for more information. So, it allows to explore the required code to get the job done.

Embedded pictures are stored as hidden attachments. As a workaround you may find the corresponding attached file (image) and then read the byte array; do the required changes.